# JpaRepository find child (pageable)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I came across a problem that I can not solve.

I want to find `Class1` elements with "Active" status, which have "Active" `status2` on `Class2` and belong to a specific `user`.

E.g.: Find all "Accepted" comments, which belong to "John" posted on post with status "Active".

I tried to use this (JpaRepository):

```
Page<Class1> findAllByStatusAndClass2StatusAndClass2User(String status, String status2, User user, Pageable pageRequest)
```

My code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class1")
public class Class1 {
...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "class1")
    private Set<Class2> class2;

    String status1;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "class2")
public class Class2 {
...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "class1_id", nullable = false)
    private Class1 class1;

    User user;       
    String status2;
...
}
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact with JPARepository, your method name and params should respect the fields names in your entities.

So you need to use `status1` instead of `status` and `Class2Status2` instead of `Class2Status`.

Your method should be like this:

```
Page<Class1> findAllByStatus1AndClass2Status2AndClass2User(String status1, String status2, User user, Pageable pageRequest)
```

Comment: Yes, i did it this way, I wrote this code from memory and an error crept in. I found a different way to do it - by search a set of Class2 (~ findByClass2StringIn). Thank you for your response:)

Comment: @MarekKoperek You are welcome, so did this work for you?